# Unable to get values in jQuery from HTML Form on submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm still working on things and I've almost got it done. The only issue I've got is in my jQuery code it don't send values to a php page. Ex: it should put "?whatever=whatever&soon=soon", but it don't. It leaves it blank.

I've tried changing code such as changing JS ids, and changing the code completely.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $userName = $("username");
var $text = $("text");
var $title = $("title");
var $chatSend = $("#chatSend");

function secret() {
    var userNameString = $userName.val();
    var textString = $text.val();
    var titleString = $title.val();

    $.get("./upload.php", {
        username: userNameString,
        text: textString,
        title: titleString
    });

    window.location.replace("success.php");

    }
}
```

I expected it to put in my values (to my MySQL table), but instead they're all blank.

Here's my form. (When clicked on chatSend, it does the jQuery functions.)

```
<div>
<input type="text" id="text" name="text">
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" hidden value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']); ?>">
                <button id="chatSend">Send</button>
</div>
```

Also, here's the upload form now that I think about it (upload.php):

```
$user = $_GET['username'];

$title = $_GET['title'];

$text = $_GET['text'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `blog` (username, title, text, view) VALUES ('$user', '$title', '$text', UUID())");
```

Comment: It should be `$("#username"), $("#text"), $("#title")`

Comment: Use debugger to see what values are passed on the submission of form like this:
`function secret() { 
   debugger;
...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the proper identifier like you have with chatsend:

```
//# = ID
var $userName = $("#username");
var $text = $("#text");
var $title = $("#title");
```